# Why am I missing output when redirecting from process?

Tags: c#, process

I'm calling a console app using the Process class.  I'm redirecting the output to a log file, but there are more messages in the console window when I'm not redirecting the output than are in the log file when I am.  any ideas why?

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
string filename = @"ProgrammingMaster_LocalPowertrain.exe";
psi.FileName = filename;
string arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} false", InstanceId.ToString(), ManifestFolderPath);
psi.Arguments = arguments;
LogMessage(msgType.Warning, filename + " - " + arguments);
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
FBlockProcess = new Process();
FBlockProcess.StartInfo = psi;
FBlockProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(FBlockProcess_OutputDataReceived);
FBlockProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(FBlockProcess_ErrorDataReceived);
FBlockProcess.Start();
FBlockProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
FBlockProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

in my OutputDataReceived handler I just add the string to a ConcurrentQueue

**Edit:**
I should add that I want to capture the output in real time or close to it.  The process can take over 30 minutes to run, I don't want to have to wait that long to see what is going on.

**Update:**
After the first four lines are output, the OutputDataReceived eventHandler is never called, even though I know there are 10 or 15 more lines output to the console when I'm not redirecting.  Any ideas on what could cause that?

Comment: Possibly to do with flushing of the streams?

Comment: Do you call WaitForExit() before closing the streams?

Comment: @codymanix - no. I thought that using the events would make that unnecessary.

Comment: The process object might get garbage collected, in which case you won't get evens any more, try just storing a reference to it in a static variable and see if that fixes it, not that *that* is a solution, but it is easy to test to see if GC is the culprit here.

Comment: @Lasse - Is that necessary even if  I can see the process is still running in the Task Manager?

Comment: @Lasse - tried it anyway, that is not the problem.

Comment: @codyManix - I tried adding WaitForExit() after BeginErrorReadLine(), but that did not help.

Comment: Does the process launches another processes, are you sure  that missed messages comes from `ProgrammingMaster_LocalPowertrain.exe`

Comment: @Anton - As far as I know it doesn't launch any other processes.

Comment: @scott The process object is just a .NET object that keeps a tag on the process, it is in no way necessary for the process to stay alive. Think of it like this: You throw a paper-airplane out into the world, and ask one of your friends to watch it. If that friend decides to do something else because you lost focus on him, the airplane will still fly, it's pretty much the same deal here. However, since that's not the problem, then that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c dir *.cs";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();

    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine("Output:");
    Console.WriteLine(output);    
}
```

update

I think you can try something usefull here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx

update

I've found this link and "Solution 1" sounds to be the right way:

http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/152467/Problem-executing-a-command-line-command-from-Csha.aspx?cmt=49313#answer1

Comment: This way I won't get any of the output until it closes correct?

Comment: It looks like the same way i'm doing it.  can you see something I'm missing?

Comment: the problem with that is it compiles it all as 1 string so if you want to just read one line you can't...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to interact with an application that required authentication. Peek() would return -1 when encountering funky characters (unicode characters?) and ReadLine() was also unreliable and would eventually lockup my application since it seems the process' Standard stream was not closed.

Using the Read() method was the only way I could assure I got ALL lines and characters. Additionally, using the Process' ErrorDataReceived or OutputDataReceived event handlers also proved UNRELIABLE (missing lines). Below is how I solved my problem and insured all lines, and characters, were received:

```
process.Start();
var stdOutput = process.StandardOutput;
StringBuilder fullMessage = new StringBuilder();
while (true)
{
    var character = (char)stdOutput.Read();
    fullMessage.Append(character);

    //Print Out All Characters
    Console.Write(character);
    if (fullMessage.ToString().EndsWith("Enter Password: "))
    {
        //Submit Password To Application
        using(StreamWriter writer = process.StandardInput){
            writer.Write("somepassword");
            writer.Flush();
        }

        break;
    }
}
```